# unexpected token & при вызове метода html()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Есть блок `script` на `html` странице.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function DescContent() {
            $(".nav.nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");
            $(".nav.nav-tabs li:first-child").addClass("active");
            $("#tabContainer").html(@Model.Description);//unexpected token & при вызове метода html().
            $("#tabContainer").css({ "padding-left": "20px" });
            $("#tabContainer").css({ "padding-top": "20px" });
        }
    </script>
```

который в div `"#tabContainer"` вставляет `html` код который выглядит,вот так.

```
 <p class="m - bottom - p"><iframe style="float:left; margin:5px 25px 15px 5px;" width="350" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/csrKYk0FYpU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe><span class="font-b">some text</span> some text</p><p class="m-bottom-p"> some text.</p><ul class="list-square30"><li>some text</li></ul>
```

но вместо того чтобы обновить div и добавить вышеуказанный html код,он его преобразует в следующий вид.

`&lt;p class=&quot;m - bottom - p&quot;&gt;&lt;iframe style=&quot;float:left; margin:5px 25px 15px 5px;&quot; width=&quot;350&quot; height=&quot;250&quot; src=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/csrKYk0FYpU&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen=&quot;&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;font-b&quot;&gt;OCD5-1999&lt;/span&gt;  some text &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p class=&quot;m-bottom-p&quot;&gt; some text &lt;/p&gt;&lt;ul class=&quot;list-square30&quot;&gt;&lt;li&gt;some text языках&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li &gt; some text &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;`

из-за чего возникает ошибка.Также я пробовал это сделать через `innerhtml`.Не помогло.Я нашёл решение все литералы,заменить на соответствующие теги.Например `&gt;` на `>`,и всё выводит нормально,но хотелось бы найти более оптимальное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net по умолчанию выполняет обработку строк (*escape*), которые вы записываете во view любым способом кроме `@Html.Raw()`. Попробуйте так:

```
$("#tabContainer").html("@Html.Raw(Model.Description)");
```

Comment: Всё работает спасибо,приму ответ через минуту.